# Google map api reject key

Tags: google-maps, api-key

I'm trying to set up google map via the api on a website.
I've generated the api key on the following page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Each time that i try to load the map, Google reject the api key that I have generated.
Here's a code example taken from the google website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCz6QrORRq1YjH9YOHreY_FahL0gbvudQo&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried allowing referrers or leaving it all open but to no avail.

I guess i'm missing something, any idea?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "Google reject the api key that I have generated"? 2. What do you mean by "I tried allowing referrers or leaving it all open"?

Comment: 1/ I mean google says the key is not valid and that I need to check the documentation, where I have actually generated the key. 2/ I tried first adding the domains allowed, then removed everyting to allow any referrer to use the map with the key.

Answer (score 0):

Your key [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_mapwKey.html).  It also works if I use a key specific to [geocodezip.com](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_mapwKeyGeocodezip.html).

Maybe you have a version without the key stuck in your browser cache.